# Scala Play Framework download failed: com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.6!play_2.10.jar

Tags: scala, maven, playframework

I'm working with one of the old Scala project created using Play Framework 2.2.6. I'm trying to build and run the project locally. But, facing this error whenever I run `play clean compile`.

```sh
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.6!play_2.10.jar(src)
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.10;2.2.6!play-test_2.10.jar(src)
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: download failed: com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.6!play_2.10.jar(src)
download failed: com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.10;2.2.6!play-test_2.10.jar(src)
```

Following are the repos, I've set in `~/.sbt/repositories`.

```sh
[repositories]
maven-central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
typesafe-repo: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases
ivy-repo: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases
```

Not sure how to download these two specific mentioned in error.

Answer (score 0):

In Maven, the organization **com.typesafe.play** is closed, the repository is not available anymore.

Two choices:

1. Build or find private play repositories
2. Migrate to more recent play version (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23)

Answer (score -1):

You are getting this error because Play Framework 2.2.6 has not been compiled and released against your current Scala version which is 2.10 ([check here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play_2.10)). You should probably use different versions.

Comment: I checked 2.2.6 version for Scala and it is mentioned a 2.10. If this is incorrect, then can you please help with this?

Comment: @Kiran Can you check and see if it works if you change Play version to 2.3.0 ?